# Abstract Class and Interface in C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I read an article from some site and in that article i read this :

> Abstract classes can add more functionality without destroying the child classes that were using the old version. In an interface, creation of additional functions will have an effect on its child classes, due to the necessary implementation of interface methods to classes.

I don't understand what it means. Can anyone **explain this more specifically** , with a **Good Example** ?

this is the article which i read [Link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6118/All-about-abstract-classes)

Comment: Imagine to add a new method to an interface. All implementors will need to be updated to provide an implementation of that. Both source and binary are broken. Now add a new method to an abstract base class. Nothing will need to change (...more or less...) in derived classes. _Without destroying_ means that in this scenario an abstract base class will keep both source and binary compatibility with existing code/assemblies and an interface will break (destroy...) both.

Comment: I think it means that if you are using an interface all child classes must implement the new method in the interface. If you are using a abstract class your child classes can compile without any change because the dont have to override the abstract method or inherit the method automaticly if it is not abstract.

Comment: @Adriano Is correct answere ([Not comment](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) :-))

Comment: @pravprab well it's little bit too short for an answer and it doesn't provide any example (and I actually didn't mention that you may even add a new _abstract_ method to a base class). I hope someone else will explain that better than me!

Comment: To complete (maybe) : you can always have the abstract class implementing the interface. So when you add a functionality, you just change interface and abstract class. The new functionality can be abstract (which will force you to do something on derived classes) or virtual (or neither abstract nor virutal) in the abstract class. So you can still work with interface as much as possible, and use inheritance when "absolutely needed".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because interfaces only define members that types must implement, adding any new member to an interface will break any class that implements the old version because it inherently doesn't implement the new member.  Any time you change the definition of an interface you must change every single class that implements that interface.  Adding an abstract member to an abstract class does the same for derived classes but if you add a virtual member to the abstract class then it will have no impact on derived classes.  They can be changed to override that member but they don't have to.

Answer (score 2):

What it means is that if you consider a Abstract Class called Phone
and it has 3 virtual functions i.e. 
AddPhonePrice , AddAccessoryPrice, AddAuxillaryPrice

and if there are two child classes
1) SamsungPhone 2) Iphone

now SamsungPhone will have implementation for all 3 functions.
while Iphone will have implementation for only AddPhonePrice, since they dont provide anything else with the phone

if we make interface called IMainPhone with 
AddPhonePrice , AddAccessoryPrice, AddAuxillaryPrice functions

then both SamsungPhone and Iphone will need to implement all 3 functions 
irrespective of whether they need them or not.

Answer (score 1):

This means that you are able to add new members (methods, properties, fields, ...) to abstract classes that do not lead to changes in the derived classes - as long as the members are not abstract this is correct. For instance, consider this example:

```
internal abstract class MyBaseClass
{
    public abstract void DoSomething();

    // This method can also be added later without having an effect on the derived classes
    public virtual void DoSomethingElse()
    {
        // Do something else...
    }
}

internal class MyDerivedClass : MyBaseClass
{
    public override void DoSomething()
    {
        // Do something...
    }
}
```

In this case, the derived class has to implement the method `DoSomething`. But you can add non-abstract functions to the abstract base class later on. However, as soon as you add another abstract member to the base class, this also affects all non-abstract derived classes because the must implement the new members.
An interface on the other hand does not define concrete implementations at all but does only contain the abstract signature that all implementors must provide. Therefore, if you add a new member (method, property) to an interface it forces all implementors of the interface to also provide an implementation of the new members.

Answer (score 0):

**Interface:** When you add a method to the *base* interface class, then you have to (manually) make sure all of the *derived* classes implement that method.

**Abstract Base:** When you add a method to an abstract *base* class, you aren't required by the compiler to implement that method in the *derived* classes.